# Pila de pilas en java

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, pilas

Tengo varios proyectos finales de la materia Estructura de Datos. En todos voy bien, pero en este especifico por más que trato no logro encontrar la solución.

El problema propone lo siguiente:

> Pila de pilitas: Los elementos de la **ED PILITA** sonde cualquier tipo de dato, los elementos de la **ED PILA** son de tipo PILA.

Hasta el momento, llevo estos métodos de la clase **PILITA**

```
  public class pilita{
    Object vectorPila[];
    int tope;
    public pilita(int tam){
        vectorPila=new Object[tam];
        tope=-1;
    }
    public void inicializarPila(){
        tope=-1;
    }
    public void push(Object dato){
        tope++;
        vectorPila[tope]=dato;
    }
    public Object pop(){
        Object fuera=vectorPila[tope];
        tope--;
        return fuera;
    }
    public boolean pilaVacia(){
        return tope==-1;
    }
    public boolean pilaLlena(){
        return vectorPila.length-1==tope;
    }
    public Object cima(){
        return vectorPila[tope];
    }
    public Object contar(){
        return tope+1;
    }
}
```

Pero el problema radica en que no se como se podría implementar la combinación de **PILA** con **PILITA**. Si me pudieran ayudar a encontrar una solución se los agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 3):

Primero, yo aprovecharía en utilizar genéricos en tu clase `Pilita` para que soporte cualquier tipo y se pueda comprobar el tipo en tiempo de compilación, así evitas problemas de casteo manual en tu código. Un ejemplo base sobre tu clase:

```
public class Pilita<T> {
    Object vectorPila[];
    int tope;

    public void push(T dato){
        tope++;
        vectorPila[tope] = dato;
    }

    public T pop() {
        Object fuera = vectorPila[tope];
        tope--;
        return (T)fuera;
    }

    //demás métodos, constructores, etc
}
```

Puesto que la clase `Pilita` ya almacena una pila, lo que tu clase `Pila` puede contener es una `Pilita` de `Pilita`s:

```
public class Pila {
    private Pilita<Pilita<?>> pilaDePilas;
    int tam;

    public Pila(int tam) {
        this.tam = tam;
        pilaDePilas = new Pilita<>(tam);
    }

    //resto de métodos...
}
```